# Groovy: A groovy linkedhashmap gets converted to a new format when evaluated in a shell module

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am writing a terraform infrastructure pipeline, wherein I take multi-line string param from Jenkins, try to convert it to a map and pass it on to a terraform command.

Following is the code:

```
import groovy.json.JsonOutput

def parameters = env.params
def config
def service_map = [:]
def service_returned = [:]

node ("master"){

    withEnv(['variable="test"', 'DB_ENGINE=sqlite']) {  

        stage('Input') {
            config = readYaml text: "$parameters"
            println(config)
            config.each{ key, value ->
                service_map = "$value"
                service_returned = stringToMap(service_map)
                println(service_returned) 
            }
        }

        stage('Terraform Plan') {

            sh 
            """
            terraform init  
            terraform plan -var="instance=$service_returned"
            """

        }
    }
}

def stringToMap(service_string){
    def map = [:]
    service_string.split(" ").each { param ->
        def nameAndValue = param.split(":")
        map[nameAndValue[0]] = nameAndValue[1]
    }
    return map
}
```

When I print the service_returned map from the method "stringToMap". it gives a map like so:

```
{service="service", ec2_type="t2.micro"}
```

which is exactly what is need for terraform as a variable.

But the above code evaluates to this in the console output:

```
terraform plan -var='instance_ids=[service:"service", ec2_type:"t2.micro"]'
```

which does not work for terraform.

For reference, this is the input passed in Jenkins:

```
services:
   service:"service"
      ec2_type:"t2.micro"
```

What could be the reason for this?
Is there a way to use the same returned map in the shell module in above code?

Comment: I think the easiest way to pass map to terraform as json.

Comment: @daggett
Maybe you are talking about writing to a file, (*.tfvars.json), is that correct?

Comment: Your stringToMap code would result in exactly this output in groovy. So the question should be, why is your debug-println somewho the "correct" string.  Also I am very suprised, that something magically flattens your YAML there.

Comment: @MattDeoir, I mean you can use jsondecode in terraform https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/jsondecode.html

Comment: btw, stringToMap method returns something wrong for me..

Answer (score 0):

there is a problem in terraform command line in your code. should be `-var 'foo=bar'`

and `stringToMap` returns not a correct `go` map syntax

```
import groovy.json.JsonOutput

//i assume you got this config from yaml 
def config = [
    services:[
        service:"service",
        ec2_type:"t2.micro"
    ]
]

//function that converts groovy plain map to a go lang representation of map
def map2go(map){ 
    return "{"+map.collect{k,v-> "$k=${JsonOutput.toJson(v)}" }.join(",")+"}" 
}


goMap = map2go(config.services)

sh """
   terraform plan -var 'instance_ids=${goMap}'  
"""
```